How can I set cross-project permissions in a moderately complex architecture in Google Cloud Platform?
I am working with an architecture that spans several Google Cloud services and I need to figure out how I can configure roles and permissions to make the following scenario happen.
There is a pod running on a managed Kubernetes cluster in a project (say project-1). The kube service account is connected with an IAM service account, also in project-1.
The application running in the pod has to be able to call a Cloud Run Function gen2 (also in project-1).
The Cloud Function, in order, has to be able to access (query) a BigQuery dataset that is in another project (say project-2), via the google-cloud-bigquery library.
To summarize, there are 3 accounts involved:

The Kubernetes service account;
The IAM account connected to 1;
The Cloud Run Function service account;

The flow currently reaches the Cloud Function. The Cloud Function then fails with the following message:

google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: Table
project-2:THE_TABLE: User does not have
permission to query table
project-2:THE_TABLE, or perhaps it does not
exist.; reason: accessDenied, message: Access Denied: Table
project-2:THE_TABLE: User does not have
permission to query table
project-2:THE_TABLE, or perhaps it does not
exist.

Which is expected because none of the accounts has any BigQuery role in project-2
What roles (or permissions) exactly do I need to give to each of the accounts involved in order for this process to succede?

In your project-2 You need to grant the IAM service Account the roles/bigquery.dataviewer and roles/bigquery.dataEditor

You can use Workload Identity Federation for GKE to call your cloud run function as described in https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/workload-identity. Then you can use your IAM account for your function as described in https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#individual. Add your IAM service account in your project-2. Grant necessary permission to your IAM service account in project-2. You can get some guidelines about it in https://serverfault.com/questions/1077557/accessing-bigquery-data-from-different-project-in-same-organization-with-a-servi.
